# Appium test in Python for Android mobile client

Tags: python, appium

I am getting an error while trying to implement appium test for an Android mobile client using Python.

> `WebDriverException: Message: A new session could not be created. (Original error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Error: Command failed: ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found`

This error occurs even though I have added the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in my project path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when there is no andriod manifest file in the apk. Try to install apk.info app from playstore and you can get the details of app including manifest.

Alternatively you can pull the apk into your machine and using this tool - [Apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)
you can unpack the apk file and check if there is a manifest.xml file present